# Are grasshoppers monogamous?

Tags: zoology, ethology

Noticed two grasshoppers jumping together on the porch, and started wondering if they are monogamous? I am aware they have males and females.

Comment: Interestingly enough, there are insects that are considered to be monogamous, including cockroaches and other beetles. However, I couldn't find anything on grasshoppers.

Comment: which species - there are many grasshoppers, mating system could vary greatly within that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Male grasshoppers often mate several times with multiple female, and some females will mate again after, and perhaps even before they lay their eggs. So no, they are not monogamous.

Rufous grasshoppers for example have a very special mating cycle, the male will attract other females, possibly more than one with "pursuit sounds". After copulation, he keeps her close to prevent other males from mating with her, and the females enter a defensive mode where they refuse intercourse from other males. After laying eggs however, she enters a "relaxed" mode where she is open to others for mating.

Sources:

[jrank](http://science.jrank.org/pages/3123/Grasshoppers-Courtship-mating.html)

[Rufous grasshopper: inaturalist](http://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/rufous_grasshopper)

Comment: "some females die after lay eggs. So you could perhaps consider them monogamous" - this doesn't rule out multiple mating by males so is not monogamy